# What's the deal ForceClose.com?

Tags: discussion

So what's the deal [ForceClose.com](http://www.forceclose.com/)? *(that should be read with a Seinfeld impression)*

But seriously, it appears to be the same thing as android.stackexchange.com.  What's there relation?  Was it built before they stopped offering custom stackexchange implementations?  Does SE own it or is it completely unrelated to the SE network?  Is it going to be merged with A.SE or are the two sites rivals?  Is A.SE and ForceClose going to have a Q&A showdown at high noon to determine the top Android Answer site?  WTF!?

Comment: It looks like it's just running Stack Exchange, but not a Joel/Jeff group site. Also includes http://zergoverflow.com/, http://askaboutgadgets.com/, http://home4film.com/.. but run by http://www.siriusapplications.com and they sell tshirts?

Comment: forceclose.com web page displays:
"The website "www.forceclose.com" has been disabled. If you are the administrator of this Stack Exchange 1.0 site, please email se1-admin@stackexchange.com with any questions you may have."
Is all the data lost?

Comment: And now I get "too many redirects" from Chrome. It looks dead. I haven't checked to see how much might have been saved on the Wayback Machine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm the administrator of Force Close. Robert did offer for us to join the StackExchange 2.0 network, but I declined because I want to keep ownership of the site. I plan to move to OSQA or some other clone when our subscription expires, and I am going to continue promoting the site.

Summary: Q&A showdown at high noon.

Comment: I will still continue to support both exchanges :)

Comment: Stack Exchange works best when there's only one site for each topic.  Otherwise you're just diluting the pool of people answering and asking questions, so people are duplicating the same stuff in multiple places, not getting the answers they could, etc.  Since all our content is CC, I should be able to copy all my questions here, right?

Comment: @isaacWaller, The site does not seem to be available anymore, where have you gone?

Answer (score 3):

ForceClose was an independently-owned Stack Exchange site from when we offered subscription services. They did not wish to join with android.SE. Once their site expires, they will no longer operate using the Stack Exchange software. I do not know what their plans are for the future.

Answer (score 0):

See also ForceClose's equivalent of this question from a little while ago: [What is the relationship between ForceClose.com and the Area51 Android proposal?](http://www.forceclose.com/questions/2491/what-is-the-relationship-between-forceclose-com-and-the-area51-android-proposal)

Comment: Hrm. I'm seeing a lot of similar names between that thread and this one....