# What about the other SE site for android?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the deal ForceClose.com?](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71/whats-the-deal-forceclose-com)

My friend and I were googling and stumbled upon [another SE site for android](http://www.forceclose.com/). It seems to be an SE1.0 site, but were not sure what to make of it.

Are there plans to bring this into the fold here, or is it a completely separate topic?